# open a folder from authenticated network using java

Tags: java, smb

I want to open a folder located on remote machine through java. The main problem is that the remote machine has authentication. I have been trying to use

```
String url = "smb://10.xx.xx.xx/abc/";

NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(null, "username",  "password");
SmbFile dir = new SmbFile(url, auth);
```

but I am unable to show the folder in a window.

Is this the right way or any other library may help?

In short I want to display the folder like `Desktop.getDesktop().open(file)`.

Comment: ........ waiting for days when it will be that  easy as this pseudocode... **:'( Desktop.getDesktop().open(file)**

Comment: You cannot open the folder in a **window**. The above code you have mentioned can be used to access the folder by authentication and read or write file purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code snippet but make sure that the folder you are trying to access need to shared on the network.

```
String sharedPath = "smb://IPaddress/Content/";
NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(null, "username", "password");
SmbFile dir = new SmbFile(sharedPath, auth);
System.out.println(dir.listFiles());
for (SmbFile f : dir.listFiles())
{
    System.out.println("Source file name is: " + f.getName());
}
```